# Stumped by a simple IDE hotkey issue

Tags: zooming, shortcut, chuck

I'm using Miniaudicle (with ChucK). How do I zoom in/enlarge text? I can't figure out the keyboard shortcut for it. It's not in any of the Miniaudicle resources, and I can't do it from any of the drop-down menus at the top. I know that zooming out is CTRL + MINUS, so I figure there must be some way to zoom in. I'm running Miniaudicle 1.3 on Windows 7. Thanks!

Comment: Use _Numpad +_ to zoom in.

Comment: Thanks IKlsR! That was it. The hotkey on my keyboard is Fn (+) / (+) +. A four-key shortcut just to zoom in.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible from the menus: Edit => Preferences => Editing. There you can select the size of the font. (At least under Linux.)